# Selecting column names from a query NOT a view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to get column names from a query like you can get them from a view?  The view example is below..  I cannot use the view example as these are queries created by users and will potentially be amended often..

```
SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.ViewName')
```

Thank you in advance..

Derek.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Queries aren't objects.   They don't actually exist anywhere, except when they are running.

Comment: No, the `view` is a quesry saved in SQL. So you can read its definition from SQL Server. The query is just virtual one - there is no place where you can read columns. You can do this only if you have a table with definition of the columns of the query and generate it from that definition and in that case read  that definition. But I don't imagine why you will need that.

Comment: I need to get a list of column names selected in my query.  The example above allows me to do this only if the query is saved as a view in my database but I cannot do that.  Does this make more sense?

Comment: @DerekJee why not selecting your query into a temp table and the find the columns? you can say select a,b,c,d into #tt from yourtable where 1=2 and the analyze the temp table

Answer (score 1):

If you are on SQL Server 2012 or above, then you can use [sp_describe_first_result_set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx).

The basic gist of this Stored Procedure involves passing the query you are running as a parameter. SQL Server then describes the results it will return, including column names, datatypes, size etc.

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT * from my_table';
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am in 2005 in most instances..  So it is a no I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL2012 or higher, you can use `sp_describe_first_result_set`. For example:

```
sp_describe_first_result_set @tsql = N'EXEC dbo.usp_index'
```

with `dbo.usp_index` defined as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_index
AS 
    SELECT  object_id ,
          name ,
          type_desc
    FROM      sys.indexes
```

If you are using a version before 2012, you can achieve something similar with a CLR procedure:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void usp_describe_first_result_set(string sqlCommandText)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        DataTable schemaTable;
        SqlDataReader myReader;

        //Retrieve records from the Employees table into a DataReader.
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.CommandText = sqlCommandText;
        myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult);


        //Retrieve column schema into a DataTable.
        schemaTable = myReader.GetSchemaTable();
        int rowCount = 0;

        //For each field in the table...
        foreach (DataRow myField in schemaTable.Rows)
        {
            int column = 0;

            SqlDataRecord dataRow = new SqlDataRecord(
              new SqlMetaData("name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("column_ordinal", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("max_length ", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("precision", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("scale", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("is_unique", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("is_key ", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("source_server", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("source_database", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("source_column", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("source_schema ", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("source_table", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("is_nullable ", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("is_aliased ", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("is_computed_column ", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("is_identity_column", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("is_autoincrement ", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("is_rowversion ", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("is_hidden ", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("is_long ", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("is_readonly ", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("system_type_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("xml_collection_database", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("xml_collection_schema", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("xml_collection_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256),
              new SqlMetaData("is_column_set ", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256));


            //For each property of the field...
            foreach (DataColumn myProperty in schemaTable.Columns)
            {
                //Display the field name and value.
                if (!myProperty.ColumnName.Contains("Provider") && !myProperty.ColumnName.Contains("Assembly") && !myProperty.ColumnName.Equals("DataType"))
                {
                    dataRow.SetValue(column, myField[myProperty].ToString());

                    column++;
                }
            }

            if (rowCount == 0)
            {
                SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsStart(dataRow);
            }

            SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsRow(dataRow);

            rowCount++;
        }


        SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am in 2005 in most instances..  So it is a no I guess.

Comment: You can create a CLR function that does something similar. Is that an option ?

Comment: Ooh, that may be an option.....  Didn't particularly want to run the query to get the fieldnames as I need to do something before that but it can be an option indeed..